# boost::asio cannot receive multicast datagram from certain group

Tags: c++, boost, udp, boost-asio, multicast

I am trying to receive multicast datagrams from a radar. The radar transmits data to two multicast group addresses. One of them is 224.0.0.1:5800. The other one is 232.1.195.1:2574. I am using the boost multicast receiver example from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/receiver.cpp). All I did to the code was change the multicast port to the one I need.

However, one strange phenomenon I notice is that I can receive data from 224.0.0.1 address just fine, but not from 232.1.195.1. When I send multicast data from my own computer using boost sender code ([here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/sender.cpp)), the receiver can receive from both addresses mentioned above.

Is there any configuration that I am missing out? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Have you try to check using `tcpdump` OR `wireshark` whether packets has been set by your device and received by tcp/ip stack of your host machine?

Comment: Yes, from wireshark, I can see all the packets sent from the device to both multicast addresses.